# Is it possible to write a new keyboard layout for iPhone, iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, localization, keyboard

Can one write an add-on or an app that will add a new keyboard layout to iPhone, iPad?
I couldn't find any reference on the web to suggest either it's not possible or it's possible. But because of this my gut feeling was that it wasn't, but then I came across an app that claims to add Persian keyboard on iPad:

http://iphone.appmobilize.com/apps/172190/persisch-persian-keyboard-for-the-ipad

and:

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?mt=8&ign-lr=Lockup_r2c1&id=359932063

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not develop an add-on that will run outside of your app for iOS devices running the stock OS.  A security sandbox will prevent that from working.  An app can always create for itself a slide-up view containing a work-alike set of buttons that looks like a keyboard, but with any layout you'd like.

Answer (score 3):

hotpaw2 is absolutly right. However, inside your app you are free to do whatever. You could easily build an inputbox with a custom keyboard. I suspect that's what the other app is doing.